# SVG pattern image cut off in webkit browsers

Tags: svg

I have created pill svg which has pattern image. It looks perfect in FF, IE, Edge, but in Chrome, Opera (webkit browsers) image is cut off. This problem is also on Mac in Safari and firefox.
Here is example in codepen: http://codepen.io/reinis/pen/wWXdbz

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 240 240">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="imgpattern" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <image width="240" height="240" xlink:href="http://www.vrheadsets3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dreams-of-dali-400x400.jpg"/>
      </pattern>
  </defs>
    <path fill="url(#imgpattern)" d="M17.654,17.654C-5.93,41.238-5.878,79.528,17.77,103.176l59.448,59.448l59.606,59.606c23.648,23.648,61.938,23.7,85.522,0.116s23.532-61.874-0.116-85.522l-59.488-59.488L103.176,17.77 C79.528-5.878,41.238-5.93,17.654,17.654z" />
</svg>`

Can anybody figure out what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the viewbox to "0 0 300 300" and the image width and height to 300 as well, and in SVG you will face a lot of issues related with the viewBox, so for better understanding check this link 
https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: O, very simple solution. Thanks!!